# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError how to fix this

Tags: android

i found a code but sometimes have error :

```
StringBuilder strHeaders = new StringBuilder();
char c;
while ((c = (char)stream.read()) != -1) {
    strHeaders.append(c);
    if (strHeaders.length() > 5 && (strHeaders.substring((strHeaders.length() - 4), strHeaders.length()).equals("\r\n\r\n"))) {
        // end of headers
        break;
    }
}
```

logcat

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:140)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:125)
    at myApp.activity.com.getFromPLS.retreiveMetadata(getFromPLS.java:98)
    at myApp.activity.com.getFromPLS.refreshMeta(getFromPLS.java:76)
    at myApp.activity.com.myApp$1.run(myApp.java:371)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

error on this line

```
strHeaders.append(c);
```

please any one can help me to fix this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `char` is an unsigned type, your `while` loop condition will never be satisfied, even after `stream.read()` starts returning -1. If you don't find a `"\r\n\r\n"` sequence, the loop will never end. Write the loop like this:

```
StringBuilder strHeaders = new StringBuilder();
int c;
while ((c = stream.read()) != -1) { // DO NOT cast to char here!
    strHeaders.append((char) c);
    final int len = strHeaders.length();
    if (len > 5 && (strHeaders.substring(len - 4)).equals("\r\n\r\n"))) {
        // end of headers
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that many servers will incorrectly return `"\n\n"` as the blank line that signals the end of the header. Some may also return `"\r\r"`. Unless you control the server output and are guaranteed that it will see `"\r\n\r\n"`, your blank-line detection method needs to be written in a more robust manner.

Answer (score 0):

This has more to do with the file you are reading. If the file size is large then you will landing into this issue. The best bet will be keep a check on the file size and pipe it to smaller chunks. The more you put data in StringBuffer the more loaded your memory will be.